# Не воспринимает переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Строю диаграмму.
Так не работает.А мне необходимо с переменной

```
var data_for="{'country': 'Lithuania','litres': 501.9}, {'country': 'Czech Republic', 'litres': 301.9 }, {'country': 'Ireland','litres': 201.1}, {'country': 'Germany','litres': 165.8}, {'country': 'Australia','litres': 139.9}, {'country': 'Austria','litres': 128.3}, {'country': 'UK','litres': 99}, {'country': 'Belgium','litres': 60}, {'country': 'The Netherlands','litres': 50}";

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",

  "dataProvider": [data_for],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

Но если встать содержимое переменной в `dataProvider` все работает

```
var data_for="{'country': 'Lithuania','litres': 501.9}, {'country': 'Czech Republic', 'litres': 301.9 }, {'country': 'Ireland','litres': 201.1}, {'country': 'Germany','litres': 165.8}, {'country': 'Australia','litres': 139.9}, {'country': 'Austria','litres': 128.3}, {'country': 'UK','litres': 99}, {'country': 'Belgium','litres': 60}, {'country': 'The Netherlands','litres': 50}";

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",

  "dataProvider": [{'country': 'Lithuania','litres': 501.9}, {'country': 'Czech Republic', 'litres': 301.9 }, {'country': 'Ireland','litres': 201.1}, {'country': 'Germany','litres': 165.8}, {'country': 'Australia','litres': 139.9}, {'country': 'Austria','litres': 128.3}, {'country': 'UK','litres': 99}, {'country': 'Belgium','litres': 60}, {'country': 'The Netherlands','litres': 50}],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

пример http://jsfiddle.net/uqq2urqa/3/

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны `"`;

```
var data_for = [{'country': 'Lithuania','litres': 501.9}, {'country': 'Czech Republic', 'litres': 301.9 }, {'country': 'Ireland','litres': 201.1}, {'country': 'Germany','litres': 165.8}, {'country': 'Australia','litres': 139.9}, {'country': 'Austria','litres': 128.3}, {'country': 'UK','litres': 99}, {'country': 'Belgium','litres': 60}, {'country': 'The Netherlands','litres': 50}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqq2urqa/4/

Comment: А что это за массив `dataArr = [];` ,где он используется?

Comment: игнорируйте это. я дебагил код

Comment: без него не работает